# How can I prevent (massive) sharing of accounts on Django site?

Tags: django

First thought: to check IP's in log of each account to detect sharing and ban it, but this is pretty time-consuming

Second: to control devices per account somehow, but I have no idea how to realize that.

Suggest some ideas,
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What you can do is to invalidate existing sessions when a user logs in.**

So you need to look for the sessions in the project, and whenever somebody tries to log in (check for a [user_logged_in](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.signals.user_logged_in) event/signal globally) invalidate their existing sessions or if you want to enable only a number of concurrent sessions invalidate older existing sessions and you are done

[check how to invalidate session here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/sessions/#clearing-the-session-store)